# Can I change the appearance of the iOS Keyboard DecimalPad programmatically?

Tags: ios, swift, keyboard, inputview

[image: UIKeyboardType.DecimalPad]

I'm trying to alter the appearance of the decimal pad to do things like remove the letters and turn the decimal point into a "Done" button.

Is there a way to edit the appearance of this view or to subclass the keyboard DecimalPad?

Note: I know how to use a full custom inputView to mimic this, but I would like to use the native iOS keyboard and just tweak it slightly.

Comment: No, you can't modify the DecimalPad.

Comment: No, Its not possible but we can make new custom keyboard....